# Running mvn in background from Python Popen and thread function

Tags: python, multithreading, popen, py4j

I am implementing a gateway server automation using Py4j module.The gateway server needs to be initiated every-time the user invokes the function.The issue I am facing is that I am unable to run the function in background.
Here is the code:

```
def mvn():
logger = open("log.txt", 'w')
logger.seek(0)
thread1 = Thread(target=Popen, args=("./runJVM.sh"),kwargs=
                {"stdout":logger})
thread1.daemon = True
thread1.start()
# stdout, error = proc.communicate()
# logger.write(stdout)
logger.close()
```

There are two issues I am facing here
1)If I specify the kwargs stdout to logger (a log file to check output),it throws me an error saying that stdout has multiple arguments specified.

2)If I dont specify the stdout option, the output of the thread is displayed onto ipython terminal which is not I wanted.

All i want is to invoke the server in the background so that other functions can access the java gateway server and access the methods from the same which can be used from ipython.

You can safely assume that the mvn functions are working fine when run through the terminal directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question.

I have created a thread which will take the Popen command taking a small shell script as input and passing stdout params as kwargs so that the output is not displayed.
The server was invoked and could be used from other functions.

Hope that helps